# Fetch Images from json_decode()

Tags: json, api, getjson, serverside-javascript

My Api is returning Json data as

```
[[{"ID":"1","Image":"img01.jpg"}]]
```

I am fetching this data through api on local and trying to bind image but not able to do it .
I have tried many solution here , but Seems I am missing something

```
$url = "http://getsjobs.esy.es/api.php?ID=1&format=json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json,true);

//solution 1 
// for($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
        // echo $data[$i][0];
        // echo $data[$i][Image];

    // }


//solution 2    
// foreach ($data  as $optie ) {
    // echo "name = " . $optie['Image'] . "<br>";

// }


//solution 3 
// foreach ($data as $key => $value)
              // {
          // echo $value[0];

           // }



//solution 4           
// foreach($json['Array']['Array'] as $item) {
    // print $item['Image'];

// }

//solution 4           
//echo $data->Array->Image;
```

I am Simplying Trying to fetch value 'img01.jpg'  and want to tag to Img tag SRC .

Can anyone Please Tell What I am missing ? Any Hint will be Helpful

Comment: First of all please tag the server side language in your question although it seems to be clear you're using PHP. What is exactly going wrong? Are getting an error message when processing the API response. Please be more clear on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, and each has only one element, so it's impossible to guess which of the following is more appropriate. (If possible, get a response with more than one image to see what the structure of that JSON is like.)

```
foreach ($data[0] as $item) {
  echo $item["Image"] . "\n"; // img01.jpg
}

foreach ($data as $item) {
  echo $item[0]["Image"] . "\n"; // img01.jpg
}
```

Comment: yes , Both are giving desired results  . this is my answer , However I will expreiment by adding more elements . tnx

Comment: Can you also suggest How can I bind this Json data in img src ?